# It appears that a System.ValueTuple.dll references an older version of itself (what am I missing?)

Tags: c#, .net-core, circular-dependency

```
There was a conflict between "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" and "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".
warning MSB3277:     "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" was chosen because it was primary and "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" was not.
warning MSB3277:     References which depend on "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" [D:\Projects\api\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll].
warning MSB3277:         D:\Projects\api\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll
warning MSB3277:           Project file item includes which caused reference "D:\Projects\api\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll".
warning MSB3277:             System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL
warning MSB3277:     References which depend on "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" [].
warning MSB3277:         D:\Projects\api\packages\Azure.Core.1.25.0\lib\net461\Azure.Core.dll
```

Am I reading this wrong?  Why does it appear that the only thing referencing an older version of this package is the package itself?  How can I resolve this odd dependency?

Comment: Not older, the issue is that Azure.Core references a newer version.  The Azure team programs on an island, surrounded by an agile ocean.

Comment: But the version of the Nuget package I have installed is 4.5.  I don't have 4.3 installed.  The above trace makes it appear as though the 4.5 package references the 4.3 package.